# Binary Tree segmentation fault after implementing search function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure, binary-tree

i am trying to write a program that will do the following

```
-read a file from std in
-read each line, and add each line to a binary tree
 *if name is already in binary tree,dont add the name to the tree again but update its count of repititions
-print out the binary tree
```

the file being read in looks something like

```
dylan
bob
dylan
randall
randall
```

so when i print out the binary tree i would like it to print out

```
bob 1
dylan 2
randall 2
```

i was able to successfully print out the names without worrying about repetitions. I have commented out the blocks of code that mess my program up which is anything interacting with my search function that i added after the fact to take care of repetitions. The code builds a binary tree with each "leave" being a structure of 4 parts,the name,thecount,and the pointers to left and right childs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char* name;
    int count;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* addNode(char* string);
void insert(struct node *root, char* stringgg);
void preorder(struct node *root);
int search(struct node* leaf,char* string2find);

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    struct node *root = NULL;

    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL )
    {
        if(root == NULL)
            root = addNode(buffer);
        else

            insert(root,buffer);

    }
    preorder(root);

}

struct node* addNode(char* string)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->name = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(temp->name,string);

    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void insert(struct node *root, char* stringgg)
{
   /* int flag = 5;
    flag = search(root,stringgg);
    if(flag == 1)
        return; */

    if(strcmp(stringgg,root->name) < 0)
    {
        if(root->left == NULL)
            root->left = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->left, stringgg);
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
            root->right = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->right,stringgg);
    }
}

/*int search(struct node* leaf,char* string2find)
{
    if(strcmp(string2find,leaf->name) == 0)
    {
        leaf->count = leaf->count + 1;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(string2find,leaf->name) < 0)
    {
        return search(leaf->left,string2find);
    }
    else
    {
        return search(leaf->right,string2find);
    }
    return 0;

} */

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%s",root->name);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);

}
```

the above code prints out all the names even if there already in a tree. I was hoping that someone would be able to point out my search function errors so that it wont cause a segmentation fault when printing. Possible causes may be my inappropriate use of the return function in which i am trying to return to main if flag == 1 which means match was found so dont addnodes. but if flag does not equal 1 no match was found so go about adding nodes.

Comment: Fix this first: There is a needless new line after `else` and before `insert(root,buffer);` in your `main()` function. Make sure it s a compilable code.

Comment: And, Though has not much to do with the problem at hand, but I'l like to point that `int main()` is not necessarily `C`, `int main(void)` is!

Comment: How do you exit from the `fgets` loop?

Comment: What happened when you ran this under your friendly local debugger ?

Comment: @WedaPashi: The standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says in §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup: _[`main`] shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
parameters:
`int main(void) { /* ... */ }` … or equivalent_.  Although I always write `int main(void)` (because I compile with GCC options such as `-Wstrict-prototypes` or `-Wold-style-definition`), it is not wrong to write `int main()` as that is a function with no parameters.  As a declaration of some other function, `int otherfunc();` is wrong; it indicates 'there is no information about the parameters' and should be `int otherfunc(void);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for explaining that part. :) I have developed a habit of using `int main(void)` now. But still its a valuable part that you explained if seen from "Why to.." point of view.

Answer (score 0):

at main

```
while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL ){
    char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    if(p) *p=0;//remove '\n'
```

at addNode

```
temp->count = 1;//initialize counter
return temp;
```

at insert

```
void insert(struct node *root, char* stringgg){
    int cmp_stat = strcmp(stringgg,root->name);

    if(cmp_stat == 0)
        root->count++;
    else if(cmp_stat < 0) {
        if(root->left == NULL)
            root->left = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->left, stringgg);
    } else {
        if(root->right == NULL)
            root->right = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->right,stringgg);
    }
}
```

at preorder

```
printf("%s %d\n",root->name, root->count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in searching for the very first item in the *empty* tree — you call

```
    search(root, stringgg)
```

but `root` is `NULL`, so in `search()` you call

```
    strcmp(string2find, leaf->name)
```

with `leaf == NULL` and the program crashes.

A cure: do not search *BEFORE* you update your tree, but rather search *TO* update it.

```
struct node* update(struct node* nd, const char* str)
{
    int cmp;

    // (sub)tree is empty? - create a new node with cnt==1
    if(nd == NULL)
        return CreateNode(str);

    // test if the node found
    cmp = strcmp(str, nd->name);

    if(cmp == 0)          // YES
        nd->count ++;     // update the counter
    else if(cmp < 0)      // NO - search in a subtree
        nd->left  = update(nd->left,  str);
    else
        nd->right = update(nd->right, str);

    return nd;            // return the updated subtree
}
```

Then in `main()` you just update the tree and store it:

```
    root = update(root, buffer);
```

Actually, the `root` value will change only once, on the first call, and all subsequent assignments will not change its value. However that makes the code much more readable.